# drush aliases.drushrc.php file place and content

Tags: 6, drush, upgrading

I need to upgrade a drupal 6.20 site to drupal 7 using drush sup

Installed drush using apt-get install. Upgraded it to the last version using drush self-update command and downloded the site-upgrade extension

Put the aliases.drushrc.php file under /home/mhmd/.drush/ contains the following

```
<?php
$aliases['newnour'] = array (
'root' => '/var/www/newnour',
'uri' => 'localhost/newnour',
);
?>
```

Navigate under the project path and typed drush sup newnour gahtering info finished and at the end 
Site alias not found: newnour. See example.drushrc.php.

whoever typing drus sa lists newnour 
@newnour
@none
@self
default

So what is the problem now please help me

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd from last paragraph. Using alias drush commands should work like so: `drush @alias command`. Looks like your question has nothing to do with `sup` command of drush and it's all to do with how to use the aliases correctly in drush.

Comment: yes you are right the question about alias now not the sup command

Comment: Try setting your uri to whatever is in the sites folder e.g. sites/newnour then uri would be newnour

Comment: newnour is under /var/ww/newnour do u need me to put under the old site ?

Comment: I mean if your folder structure looks like /var/www/newnour/sites/default then your uri should be default.